# NGINX problems after uninstalling apache (duplicate server)

Tags: apache, nginx, duplicates

I tried to install NGINX on my Debian server. Before switching to NGINX I used Apache2.4 and uninstalled it before installing NGINX.

My problem now is: I can't get it to work, the error is the following: "[emerg] a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/justarandomname.conf:4"

And yes, there are many posts about this problem, but none of them fixed it for me.

Additional information:
I uninstalled Apache properly (I think) and shut it down before uninstalling. Dpkg is not detecting any apache leftovers. I deleted the apache folder.
In my sites-enabled is only "justarandomname" and "justarandomname.conf" I deleted "default" (no other hidden files in there)

NGINX had some problem while installing, but after doing it manually it worked.

"justarandomname" looks like this:

```
server {
server_name mydomain.abc www.mydomain.abc;

listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;
}
```

and my "justarandomname.conf" looks like this:

```
server {
server_name mydomain.abc www.mydomain.abc;

listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;
}
```

My nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;

        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml app$

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

EDIT: Of course I restarted the server multiple times

Comment: Did you include both justarandomname and justarandomname.conf file in your nginx.conf? It will cause problem if you have two default_server directive to the same ip:port pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your nginx.conf, you include all files under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` by

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
```

and in your `justarandomname` and `justarandomname.conf` file, you both have the same line

```
listen 80 default_server
```

That is what causing you problem. see [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)

> The default_server parameter, if present, will cause the server to become the default server for the specified address:port pair.

You can either delete the `justarandomname` or change that line in nginx.conf to

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf
```